# Matlab Machine Learning Train, Validate, Test Partitions

Tags: matlab, validation, machine-learning

I'm using Matlab's Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox to create decision trees, ensembles, Knn models, etc. I would like to separate my data into training/testing partitions, then have the models train and cross validate using the training data (essentially splitting the training data into training and validation data) while preserving my testing data for error metrics. It is important that the models not be trained in any way using the testing data. For my decision tree, I have something like the following code:

```
chess = csvread(filename);
predictors = chess(:,1:6);
class = chess(:,7);

cvpart = cvpartition(class,'holdout', 0.3);
Xtrain = predictors(training(cvpart),:);
Ytrain = class(training(cvpart),:);
Xtest = predictors(test(cvpart),:);
Ytest = class(test(cvpart),:);


% Fit the decision tree
tree = fitctree(Xtrain, Ytrain, 'CrossVal', 'on');

% Error Metrics
testingLoss = loss(tree,Xtest,Ytest,'Subtrees','all'); % Testing
resubcost = resubLoss(tree,'Subtrees','all'); % Training
[cost,secost,ntermnodes,bestlevel] = cvloss(tree,'Subtrees','all'); % Cross Val
```

However, this returns

```
Undefined function 'loss' for input arguments of
type 'classreg.learning.partition.ClassificationPartitionedModel'.
```

when attempting to find the testing error. I have tried several combinations of similar methods using different types of classification algorithms, but keep coming back to not being able to apply test data to a cross validated model due to partitioned data. How am I supposed to apply test data to a cross validated model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use cross validation in the call to fitctree, by default 10 model folds are constructed within the 70% of data used to train the model. You can find the kFoldLoss (within each model fold) via:

```
modelLoss = kfoldLoss(tree);
```

Since the original call to fitctree constructed 10 model folds, there are 10 separate trained models. Each of the 10 models is contained within a cell array, located at tree.Trained . For for example you could use the first trained model to test the loss on your held out data via:

```
testingLoss = loss(tree.Trained{1},Xtest,Ytest,'Subtrees','all'); % Testing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the kfoldLoss function to also get the CV loss for each fold and then choose the trained model that gives you the least CV loss in the following way:

```
modelLosses = kfoldLoss(tree,'mode','individual');
```

The above code will give you a vector of length 10 if you have done 10-fold cross-validation while learning. Assuming the trained model with least CV error is the 'k'th one, you would then use:

```
testSetPredictions = predict(tree.Trained{k}, testSetFeatures);
```